# Error while trying to decompose a time series: non-numeric argument

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to R and am working on an assignment where I import some JSON data to (1) create a time series graph and (2) decompose the time-series. It's the decompose function where I'm struggling. Here is what works...

```
# Import JSON & convert to data.frame
aor <- fromJSON.....
aor <- as.data.frame......

# Combine the year and month into a date format
aor$date <- as.yearmon(paste(aor$year, aor$month), "%Y %m")

# Ensure data is float not chr
aor$mwh <- as.numeric(aor$mwh)

# Prep the data.frame for time-series analysis by converting to xts
aor <- xts(x = aor, order.by = aor$date)

# Successfully output a time-series graph.
dygraph(aor)
```

Here is a sample of aor up to this point...

```
> aor
         mwh         date      
Jan 2001 "  1.42000" "Jan 2001"
Feb 2001 "  1.28400" "Feb 2001"
Mar 2001 "  1.25800" "Mar 2001"
Apr 2001 "  1.53600" "Apr 2001"
May 2001 "  1.47100" "May 2001"
Jun 2001 "  1.91800" "Jun 2001"
Jul 2001 "  2.37800" "Jul 2001"

> dput(head(aor, 10))
 
structure(c("  1.42000", "  1.28400", "  1.25800", "  1.53600", 
"  1.47100", "  1.91800", "  2.37800", "  2.47000", "  1.65100", 
"  1.58100", "Jan 2001", "Feb 2001", "Mar 2001", "Apr 2001", 
"May 2001", "Jun 2001", "Jul 2001", "Aug 2001", "Sep 2001", "Oct 2001"
), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("mwh", "date")))
```

The code I thought would produce the decomposition graphic...

```
ts <- as.ts(aor)

> ts
             mwh     date
Jan  1   1.42000 Jan 2001
Feb  1   1.28400 Feb 2001
Mar  1   1.25800 Mar 2001
Apr  1   1.53600 Apr 2001
May  1   1.47100 May 2001
Jun  1   1.91800 Jun 2001
Jul  1   2.37800 Jul 2001


d <- decompose(ts)
plot(d)
```

I get this error when trying to decompose ts...

> Error in `-.default`(x, trend) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: hi, can you share your data using `dput`: simply type `dput(head(aor, 10))` and post the result inside your question.

Comment: @Cettt Thanks, I just did that.

Comment: In the data you provided hte column `mwh` is not numeric but character with leading white spaces. This could be the issue.